# Accidentally moved files with the find command to a non-existing folder

Tags: files, directory, find

I ran the following command:

```
find . -type f -name '*HEIC.jpg' -exec mv '{}' /media/bkup/New_folder/103APPLE/test_2 \
```

TEST_2 folder does not exist, I have a TEST 2 (no underscore), but the command wouldn't work with space in there.

The files aren't in the source folder, nor did the TEST_2 folder gets created.

Any way I can get to the files / recover them? tx

Comment: All but the last file `find`ed is lost. The last file is now `/media/bkup/New_folder/103APPLE/test_2`. A better practice is to use `mv --target-directory=/media/bkup/New_folder/103APPLE/test_2` with `find`.

Comment: ... another good habit is to always end the target with a `/`, which will cause `mv` to error out if it either doesn't exist or is a plain file

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. It wasnt something important, thank god...